# Large cookie causing slowness issue in application

Tags: php, performance, amazon-web-services, cookies, jwt

We have our production infrastructure in AWS. The servers are located in Ireland (eu-west-1) and our customer base is in UAE and Saudi Arabia. Our application is PHP based (Symfony + Yii).

Recently, we deployed the JWT token functionality and we started facing slowness issue. The requests would take ~2 minutes to load.

After much investigation we found that this was happening because of `jwtTokenCookie` in the browser cookie. We tried with / without any random large cookie and this affected the slowness issue.

This happens only in UAE and Saudi Arabia, but not in Germany and Poland, for example.

- Dubai + Large cookie = Slowness issue
- Dubai + No large cookie = No issue
- Poland + Large cookie = No issue
- Poland + No large cookie = No issue
- Dubai (Germany VPN) + Large cookie = No issue
- Dubai (Germany VPN) + No Large cookie = No issue

Please help!

Comment: May be some country level ISP data capturing? I suggest you open a ticket with AWS also in the meantime you seek an answer here

Comment: This smells a lot like some inspection issue on the ISP/government side that gives this issue. I would second trying opening at support ticket with AWS, but there is likely nothing that AWS can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with https request, and see if you find any difference in slowness, If it improves, than it establishes the fact that someone is processing the cookie data on the way over http. - solution is to go with https

Comment: You are absolutely right. Just like other people have mentioned, our guess was that there is some inspection of headers from the government side. We tried with https and there was no issue.